# Can we write javascript code in twig template?

Tags: 8

Can we write javascript code in twig template?

Its needed to write javascript code in twig template.

When we are writting the same code in custom.js file that particular code is not working in it.

How to write javascript code directly into the twig template?

Comment: The code in your js file maybe  doesn't work because the HTML is not rendered yet. Try to write your code in a document.ready function or use $('body').on('click', selector,function()) instead of $(selector).click(function());  Also check if you get any errors in your console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can write JS code in a twig template. I can't think of any syntax crossovers so you should be able to literally write it as-is.

Indeed this works fine in html.twig.html:

```
<script>
  (function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  })('test');
</script>
```

If you're having syntax trouble, you can always escape it with `raw`, but it should be unnecessary:

```
{% raw %}
<script>
  (function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  })('test');
</script>
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: thanks clive and whats about the php code can we use directly into twig template as javascript.

Comment: You need to [preprocess](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates) it to get php vars into twig, you can't add php code to a template. Well you can, but it won't be executed

Comment: For me, inside of a **Global: Custom Text** field not even `{% raw %}` worked, do you know why or how one can fix that?

Comment: A text field isn’t a template so will probably be stripped for dangerous tags @Top-Master